# C# Task gets stuck and wont do anything

Tags: c#, multithreading, godot

I have this code:

```
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task t1 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => {

        try{
            ImageCreator ic = new ImageCreator();
        terrainTexture = ic.createImageFromData(textureData.heightImageData, data.width, data.height);
        textures.terrainTexture = terrainTexture;
        }catch(Exception e){
            GD.Print(e.StackTrace);
        }

    });

    System.Threading.Tasks.Task t2 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => {

        ImageCreator ic = new ImageCreator();
        soilTexture = ic.createImageFromData(textureData.soilThicknessImageData, data.width, data.height);

         textures.soilTexture = soilTexture;

    });

    System.Threading.Tasks.Task t3 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => {

        ImageCreator ic = new ImageCreator();
        normalTexture = ic.createImageFromData(textureData.normalImageData, data.width, data.height);
        textures.normalTexture = normalTexture;

    });

    System.Threading.Tasks.Task t = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll(t1,t2,t3);

    t.Wait();
```

And the method in question:

```
class ImageCreator{
public ImageTexture createImageFromData(byte[] imageData, int width, int height){
    ImageTexture itex = new ImageTexture();
    Image image = new Image();
    image.CreateFromData(width, height, false, Image.Format.Rgb8, imageData);
    itex.CreateFromImage(image);
    itex.Flags = 5;
    return itex;
}
```

}

The goal of this piece is to run 3 tasks in parallel. Each task creates Texture from provided data. Without threading it runs just fine. But when i added in this paralleilization it wont run anymore. It seems to be getting stuck at new ImageTexture(). I have tried different approaches but none seems to work. At first the createImageFromData method was a static method, but then i read that static + threading might not be the best thing, so i created a object with the method. But still it gets stuck at the same place. There are no exceptions thrown. It just gets stuck and nothing happens.

Where have i gone wrong?

Minimal code that causes the issue:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ImageTexture> t1 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        ImageTexture itex = new ImageTexture();
    });
```

Task starts but it never ends and there are no other tasks running at the same time. At least i dont know any other task running.

Comment: I guess as you are using the same object inside each task textureData, textures, ... there is a chance of deadlock.... check it

Comment: texture was outside of the tasks before. So it must be textureData. So how can i access the 3 different fields from 3 different threads at the same time. Or its not possible ?

Comment: `But still it gets stuck at the same place` - https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: How is this code called, and what's with the last `t.Wait()`? Are you using `.Wait()` anywhere else?

Comment: public static MapTextures MapDataToTexture(MapData data). Both MapData and MapTextures is a struct. and this is the only wait im using.

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works,

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<object> t3 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {

        ImageCreator ic = new ImageCreator();
        return ic.createImageFromData(textureData.normalImageData, data.width, data.height);    
    });
```

After calling WhenAll().Wait(), try to assign the value. That may fix your issue.

Comment: Still. It get s stuck at ImageTexture itex = new ImageTexture(); Its like the constructor or something goes into deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue comes from Godot.ImageTexture constructor. For some reason it gets stuck when created on a thread. Maybe some context issue or something.

```
ImageTexture terrainTexture = new ImageTexture();
    ImageTexture soilTexture = new ImageTexture();
    ImageTexture normalTexture = new ImageTexture();
    byte[] heightImageData = textureData.heightImageData;
    byte[] soilImageData = textureData.soilThicknessImageData;
    byte[] normalImageData = textureData.normalImageData;
    int width = data.width;
    int height = data.height;
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task t1 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        createImageFromData(heightImageData, terrainTexture, width, height);
    });

    System.Threading.Tasks.Task t3 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        createImageFromData(normalImageData, normalTexture, width, height);
    });

    System.Threading.Tasks.Task t = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll(t1,t3);

    t.Wait();
```

But this code works just fine.